# registerHelper weird error with latest Handlebars and EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I get an undefined variable in the console log using the latest Handlebars and EmberJS inside a registerHelper function:

http://jsfiddle.net/qqeQj/1/

However when using emberJS 0.9.8.1 without the Handlebars it works as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/qqeQj/2/

Any ideas??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all currently released versions of Ember, we include Handlebars. By including it yourself, I suspect that the two versions are conflicting in unexpected ways.

We will likely be splitting Handlebars out from the built "ember.js" in the 1.0 release, but until then, you should not include it yourself.

Comment: But when I exclude the handlebars.js I get Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars 1.0.beta.5 or greater 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'registerHelper' of undefined

Comment: The issue here is that we've changed the way Handlebars contexts are managed in master. The `{{view}}` helper no longer changes context by default. So `this` in your helper is still the person object, not the view. In general, I would not recommend using master unless you're very confident in what you're doing.